# Modify mail on user-creation

Tags: joomla-3.x, user, emails, registration, email-template

at the moment I'm getting the following mail an user-creation:

```
Hallo Lastname Fristname,


diese E-Mail-Adresse wurde von einem Administrator auf der Seite example.com für einen neuen Benutzer registriert.

Es folgen Benutzername und Passwort zur Anmeldung auf der Seite http://example.com/

Benutzername: myusername
Passwort: $2y$10$YPB0TVz.1jz4G


Bitte auf diese Nachricht nicht antworten da sie automatisch vom System erstellt wurde und nur zur Information dient.
```

How can I prevent the mail from being sent and use my own text?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Registration message comes from Language Variable defined in com_users language file:

> \language\en-GB\en-GB.com_users.ini

Replace en-GB with your desired language code of course.

You should search your message in the above file and instead of directly editing .com_users.ini which might get overwritten in next joomla update,  you should create language override.

Please check the following link how to override the langauge:

http://docs.joomla.org/Language_Overrides_in_Joomla

Comment: Okay, thanks a lot. 

Is it possible to completely disable this notification?

Comment: Disabling Registration Message without disabling Registration itself is not possible.

Comment: Would it be possible to disable user registration but still use the User-Object to add users? If this is possible: Will there still be registration-mails if JUser is user?

Comment: I wouldn't know that. I am just an integrator, not a developer. Ask another question of that matter. If you are satisfiied with this answer, please accept it.